# How to display property from FK obj but edit the ID when editting the datafield?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

In my Grid viewmodel I have an whole obj that has two foreign keys in it and I need to have them display a property they have ( a string obj) as the text and the value that will be editted would be the foreign key id. Right now all I have is it displaying parts of the obj in the grid on my webpage but where the FK fields are is just displays a path not the data. I am using MVC with EF

```
public class Bug
{
    public int BugId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BugType")]
    public int BugTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual BugType BugType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BugStatus")]
    public int BugStatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual BugStatus BugStatus { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
}

public class BugType
{
    public int BugTypeId { get; set; }
    public string BugTypeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class BugStatus
{
    public int BugStatusId { get; set; }
    public string BugStatusName { get; set; }
}
public class BugJqGridViewModel
{
    public JQGrid Grid { get; set; }

    public BugJqGridViewModel()
    {
        Grid = new JQGrid
        {
            Columns = new List<JQGridColumn>()
                             {
                                 new JQGridColumn{ DataField="BugId", 
                                                   PrimaryKey = true,
                                                   Editable = false,
                                                   Width = 100 },                                      
                                 new JQGridColumn{ DataField="BugType", 
                                                   Editable = true,
                                                   Width = 175, }, 
                                 new JQGridColumn{ DataField="BugStatus", 
                                                   Editable = true,
                                                   Width = 175, },
                                 new JQGridColumn{ DataField="DateReported", 
                                                   Editable = false,
                                                   Width = 175, 
                                                   DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}"  }, 
                                 new JQGridColumn{ DataField="Description",
                                                   Editable = false,
                                                   Width = 800 }                                    
                             },
            Width = Unit.Pixel(1425),
            Height = Unit.Percentage(100)
        };

        Grid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;  
    }
}
```

SetupEditdropdownlist method 
I was trying to recreate this method to suit my needs but I ran into a problem with the FK id cant be converted into a string at this point.  I am not sure if I am going the right direction with this or not because of the FK

```
        private void FunctionalityContextMenu_SetUpBugIDEditDropDown(JQGrid grid)
    {
        // setup the grid search criteria for the columns
        JQGridColumn bugTypeColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "BugType");
        bugTypeColumn.Editable = true;
        bugTypeColumn.EditType = EditType.DropDown;

        JQGridColumn bugStatusColumn = grid.Columns.Find(c => c.DataField == "BugStatus");
        bugStatusColumn.Editable = true;
        bugStatusColumn.EditType = EditType.DropDown;

        // Populate the search dropdown only on initial request, in order to optimize performance
        if (grid.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData)
        {
            var db = new GameDevCupidContext();
            var editList = from bug in db.Bugs
                           select new SelectListItem
                           {
                               Text = bug.BugType.BugTypeName,
                               Value = bug.BugTypeId // accepts a only a string
                           };

            bugTypeColumn.EditList = editList.ToList();

            var editList1 = from bug in db.Bugs
                            select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = bug.BugStatus.BugStatusName,
                                Value = bug.BugStatusId // Accepts only a string
                            };

            bugStatusColumn.EditList = editList1.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a situation to my own problem.  Apparently, you have to join the tables together then bind them to the grid.

```
public JsonResult EmployeeJqGridDataRequested()
{
      var bugGridModel = new BugJqGridViewModel();

      var db = new bugContext();
      var bugs = from b in db.Bugs
                 join bt in db.BugTypes on b.BugTypeId equals bt.BugTypeId
                 join bs in db.BugStati on b.BugStatusId equals bs.BugStatusId
                 select new { b.BugId, bt.BugTypeName, bs.BugStatusName,b.DateReported,b.Description };
      return bugGridModel.Grid.DataBind(bugs);
}
```